# I Need Help Modifying CKEditor's Default Image Property Paths

Tags: drupal-6, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKEditor with Drupal 6.19. I have tried my installation with both CKFinder and IMCE. When an image is inserted from the image browser into the Image Properties window, CKEditor gets a url similar to:

/sites/example.com/files/images/my_image.jpg

I want CKEditor to simply have:

/files/images/my_image.jpg

file structure of my site is this:

/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor
/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckfinder
/sites/all/modules/imce
/sites/example.com/files/images/my_mages.jpg

Is this url passed from the file browser, or a default in CKEditor?

If it is CKEditor, where do I find the code to change this, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The URL suggested `/sites/example.com/files/images/my_image.jpg` is the correct path. Thats because all files are uploaded to the `/sites/example.com/files/` folder. The behavior is correct and should not be modified. (Unless I've not understood your problem correctly or there is a very good reason why you want to store your images under `DRUPAL_ROOT/files/images`)